# I am getting this error"Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

Tags: ssis

```
DECLARE @Date DATE
DECLARE @FileName VARCHAR(1000)
DECLARE @FilePath VARCHAR(8000)

SET @FilePath = 'S:\FFgh\ENG\dataload'
SELECT @FileName = REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(REPLACE@FilePath,'.DAT','')),1,CHARINDEX '\',REVERSE(REPLACE(@FilePath,'.DAT','')))-1))

SELECT @Date = CAST(Date AS DATE) FROM FileHeader Where FinalName = @FileName

SELECT CAST(@Date AS DATETIME) AS Date, @@ROWCOUNT AS HeaderFooter
```

Here Is my code if I use file name instead of @FileName it works, otherwise gives me error.

Comment: When you encounter the error, what is the value of `Date` in that record?

Comment: Here is the date Value '2014-16-09'

Comment: `SELECT [Date], IsDate([Date]) AS IsDate FROM FileHeader Where FinalName = @FileName`

Comment: What language is your server using? If it's not France, that's not a valid date

Answer (score 0):

Found a couple of brackets missing by `REPLACE` and `CHARINDEX`. Added below ..

```
DECLARE @Date DATE
DECLARE @FileName VARCHAR(1000)
DECLARE @FilePath VARCHAR(8000)

SET @FilePath = 'S:\FFgh\ENG\dataload'
SELECT @FileName = REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(REPLACE(@FilePath,'.DAT','')),1,CHARINDEX ('\',REVERSE(REPLACE(@FilePath,'.DAT','')))-1))

SELECT @Date = CAST(Date AS DATE) FROM FileHeader Where FinalName = @FileName

SELECT CAST(@Date AS DATETIME) AS Date, @@ROWCOUNT AS HeaderFooter
```

Comment: Thanks my pear set the string wrong still thank you!!

Comment: @Cool1 .. Did you try what billinkc suggested to use `SELECT [Date], IsDate([Date]) AS IsDate FROM FileHeader Where FinalName = @FileName`. The result returned should give you info on what might be the cause of the error